# Regex for capturing a character between a group but ignoring the ones in a nested group

Tags: php, regex

This is for make something similar to "templates" in MediaWiki with PHP in order to make the parameters between nested templates work.

Is possible with a regex to capture all occurrences of a character between braces but ignoring occurrences of it if it occurs in a nested group of braces?

```
| {{ | {{ | }} | | }} |
```

Highlighted:

```
| {{ *|* {{ | }} *|* *|* }} |
```

Comment: @drewk, if anyone can answer this, it's you. I saw you perform regex miracles today :)

Comment: @peroyomas: As many have said, you need to be very careful using a regex in this situation. A regex *could* separate these out, but may react badly on similar strings with subtle differences or with braces that do not close in the same way. If you are confident that the braces will all close and the depth will be the same, you can use a regex -- otherwise use a parser type approach. A parser does not need to be difficult at all, it is just a different and perhaps more robust approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
m/.*{{([^{]+)}}/
```

that would capture a group between {{ and }} so long as '{' wasn't present - syntax is perl

though this is better done with a parser

edited again.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr, I think you intend on having that `+` inside the capture group.

Comment: Your posted regex captures this: "{{ | }} | | }}" from | {{ | {{ | }} | | }} |. The first pipe is missed...

Answer (score 0):

No, you must write a context-free grammar (or Perl recursive regexps) to parse it. What are the ignored nested templates replaced by?

The parser will look like this in pseudocode:

```
input = "| {{ | {{ | }} | | }} |", pointer = 0;
char = '', results = [];

read_next_char() {
  return input[++ pointer];
}

go_back_one_char() {
  pointer --;
}

while (char = read_next_char()) {
  if (char == '{') {
    if (read_next_char() == '{') InsideBraces();
    else go_back_one_char();
  }
}

InsideBraces(skipping=false) {
  result = "";
  while (char = read_next_char()) {
    if (char == '{') {
      if (read_next_char() == '}') InsideBraces();
      else go_back_one_char();
    } else if (char == '}') {
      if (read_next_char() == '}') break;
      else go_back_one_char();
    } else {
      result += char;
    }
  }
  if (!skipping) results.push(result);
}
```

Comment: PHP also has the capability to do recursive regex matching.