# Using PHP and regex, insert a character between a group of matched characters

Tags: php, regex

I would like to insert a character between a group of matched characters using regex to define the group and PHP to place the character within the match.  [Looking here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597429/regex-for-capturing-a-character-between-a-group-but-ignoring-the-ones-in-a-nested)  I see that it may require PHP recursive matching, although I imagine there could be a simpler way.

To illustrate, I am attempting to insert a space in a string when there is a combination of 2 or more letters adjacent to a number.  The space should be inserted between the letters and number(s).  The example, "AXR900DE3", should return "AXR 900 DE 3".

Could an answer be to use preg_split to break up the string iteratively and insert spaces along the way?
I've begun an attempt using preg_replace below for the pattern 2+letters followed by a number (I will also need to use a pattern, a number followed by 2+letters), but I need another step to insert the space between that match.

```
$sku = "AXR900DEF334";
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=[A-Z]{2}[\d])/',' ', $sku);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to do recursive.
If I have understood you correctly, you should be able to do this:

```
$sku = "AXR900DEF334";
$string = preg_replace('/((?<=[A-Z]{2})(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z]{2}))/',' ', $sku);
echo $string;
```

**OUTPUT**

> AXR 900 DEF 334

This will match both when the letters precedes and comes after the digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this php code:

```
<?php
$sku = "AXR900DEF334";
$s = preg_replace('/(?<=[A-Z]{2})([\d])/', ' $1', $sku);
var_dump($s);
?>
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(14) "AXR 900DEF 334"
```

Comment: There should be a space between the "900" and "DEF," too.

Comment: @Josh M. I thought OP wrote `attempting to insert a space in a string when there is a combination of 2 or more letters adjacent to a number` and 900DEF starts with a number so doesn't match with above statement.

Comment: Not sure - to me it sounded like it could be AA00 or 00AA and in both cases a space should be inserted. We'll see.

Comment: Yes, a space would be inserted in both spaces.  What does the "$1" do in ' $1' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$sku = "AXR900DEF334";
$string = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2,})([\d])/','\1 \2', $sku);
echo "$string\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use two expressions:

Add a space between characters and numbers:

```
$sku = "AXR900DEF334";
$sku = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2,})([\d])/','\1 \2', $sku);
```

And then add a space between numbers and characters:

```
$sku = preg_replace('/([\d])([A-Z]{2,})/','\1 \2', $sku);
```